# Angular 2 : Validators, ReactiveForms, FormBuilder and custom classes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Let's say you have this class

```
export class User {
    username = '';
    password = '';
}
```

When you make a reactive form, you can do it like this

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
    username: ''
    password: ''
});
```

Or, second way

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group(new User());
```

My problem comes with the second way : when you use the first way, you can add **Validators** to your controls like this

```
username: ['', Validators.required],
password: ['', Validators.required]
```

But with the second way, **how can you add Validators to your form controls ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let control = this.form.controls["username"];
let newValidators = Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(255)])
control.setValidators(newValidators);
control.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: I just stubbed on this (well almost this) with `this.userForm.get('username').setValidators([Validators.required])` seconds after posting this ahah. Anyway, it's very close from what I used, so I will mark your answer as the accepted one, thank you !

Comment: (Ok I will accept it in 9 minutes, SOF is not OK with that)